# Porque el grafico de línea une los puntos en un orden no secuencial?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy graficando en linea la ocurrencia de un evento mensual, y por el contrario aparece como una red?

```
Tendencia_robo_x_municipio = Tendencia_robo_x_municipio[Tendencia_robo_x_municipio['fecha'] >= '2020-09-01']
x=Tendencia_robo_x_municipio['fecha']
y_med=Tendencia_robo_x_municipio['MEDELLÍN']
y_bell=Tendencia_robo_x_municipio['BELLO']

#Personalización de la gráfica
# to plot the graph
#Tendencia_robo_x_municipio.plot(x="Periodo de Tiempo", y="Evolución Robo de Medidores Ciudad de Medellín", kind="line")
plt.plot_date(x, y_med,linestyle ='solid')
plt.plot(x,y_med,marker="^")
plt.plot(x,y_bell,marker="^")
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(22, 7)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

se visualiza actualmente así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me gustaria que se viera así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es una muestra de los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y los datos como vienen? Pon una muestra.

Comment: es muy probable que tus datos originales estén desordenados, ordena tus datos haciendo `df_ordenada = Tendencia_robo_x_municipio.sort(by=['fecha'])` y luego saca los valores de ese dataframe ordenado `x=df_ordenada['fecha']` y así... el resto del código dejalo y listo

Comment: ok, voy a ensayar lo que me dices y les comento ...

Comment: Heyyyyyyyy nychas gracias Ulises Bussi, : el cambio fue por : df_ordenada = Tendencia_robo_x_municipio.sort_values(by=['fecha'])  ya que sort() esta obsoleta y cambio por sort_values(), quedó perfecto...